# Spring MVC. Sometimes http request running too long

Tags: java, spring, http, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am using HandlerInterceptor for calculating time of execution request. Most http requests to controller, that just returns String, running about 20ms, but 2% of requests running 250-1000ms. Server Tomcat 7.

Interceptor code

```
public class Interceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    private static final String START_TIME_OF_REQUEST = "startTimeOfRequest";

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        request.setAttribute(START_TIME_OF_REQUEST, System.currentTimeMillis());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        Long timeFinish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Long timeStart = (Long)request.getAttribute(START_TIME_OF_REQUEST);
        logTime(timeFinish - timeStart);
    }
}
```

Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/testRequest")
    public String testRequest() {
        return "{\"message\":\"ok\"}";
    }
}
```

log file with time(ms) of requests:

```
 [catalina-exec-152] INFO  - 12
 [catalina-exec-191] INFO  - 14
 [catalina-exec-193] INFO  - 42
 [catalina-exec-187] INFO  - 13
 [catalina-exec-200] INFO  - 14
 [catalina-exec-207] INFO  - 17
 [catalina-exec-151] INFO  - 13
 [catalina-exec-204] INFO  - 15
 [catalina-exec-208] INFO  - 72
 [catalina-exec-177] INFO  - 15
 [catalina-exec-186] INFO  - 460
 [catalina-exec-191] INFO  - 269
 [catalina-exec-158] INFO  - 16
 [catalina-exec-151] INFO  - 58
 [catalina-exec-170] INFO  - 21
 [catalina-exec-193] INFO  - 329
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you doing many concurrent requests? Perhaps your Servlet Container configuration has all threads busy and some requests are waiting for a free Thread in the pool

Comment: Could also be doing full GCs.

Comment: Nobody can tell you the cause of this without seeing the code of your controller, service layer and repository layer. The cause could be any number of things.

Comment: Profiling to understand the bottleneck and then tuning can help.

Comment: Please also provide your interceptor config, where your actually adding them, aren't they also for static resources for example?